# non mandatory parameter in a friendly-url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I want to write a pretty url for `someone.php` directory. prolem is it sometimes expects two paramters and sometimes just one. I couldn't handle second parameter.

I can write easily for just 1 parameter

```
RewriteRule ^someone/([^.?/]+)$  /someone.php?someone=$1 [L]
```

Howevever i couldn't succeed when i try to add a second parameter. I tried something like this

```
RewriteRule ^someone/([^.?/]+)/([^.?/]*)$  /someone.php?someone=$1&topic=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the second second capture group  optional in your Regex pattern so that the rule can handle both of your new  urls.

```
^someone/([^.?/]+)/?([^.?/]*)?$
```

The pattern above would match both uris `/someone/foo/bar` and `/someone/foo` .

Here is your complete Rule

```
RewriteRule ^someone/([^.?/]+)/?([^.?/]*)?$  /someone.php?someone=$1&topic=$2 [L]
```

Comment: answer that comes late :)